# Background image flickering when mouseover - IE

Tags: internet-explorer, image, background

I have a contact form and I added an image as a background. The background image is flickering when I move the mouse over the fields in IE(6,7,8).

If I remove the contact form (made with divs) everything is fine. I tried to build the form with table and I have the same problem.

Any solution?

Every idea is welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known problem that you can fix by picking a solution from this Google search:
http://www.google.com/search?q=internet+explorer+background+flickering

It basically amounts to adding the following Javascript code to the page:

```
try {
  document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
} catch(e) {}
```

Does that help at all?